# Java - Clicking with Robot

Tags: java, swing

This is the code I currently have.

```
        timer = new Timer(Integer.parseInt(ms.getText()), new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (isRunning) {
                    frame.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
                    robot.mouseMove(clickX, clickY);
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                    frame.toFront();
                    frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
```

I am trying to have the window restore after it clicks the certain point. This is what I have so far, but the only thing not working anymore is the clicking. It moves the mouse to the point, but doesn't click. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to `mouseRelease()`:

```
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

Otherwise it's equivalent to clicking and holding down with the robot.